# the image gets uploaded to the folder even if validation fails - node js and multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

i have made a global error handling file, the problem is if there is some validation error the image doest not get inserted in db but gets uploaded in image folder how can i solve it the image should not upload when validation fails

```
const Image = require("../models/Image");
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler");
const catchAsyncError = require("../middlewares/catchAsyncerrors");

exports.addImage = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  const image = req.file ? req.file.filename : null;
  const { title, description, keywords } = req.body;

  if (!title || !description || !keywords || !image) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("pls enter the required fields", 400));
  }
  const result = await Image.create({
    title,
    description,
    keywords,
    image,
  });

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    message: "added",
  });
});
```

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.route("/upload").post(upload.single("image"), addImage);
```

Comment: Validate before multer middleware